# What is the default padding for int field in BeanIO?

Tags: marshalling, padding, bean-io

What is the default padding for *int* field in BeanIO if nothing is specified? For example in the following case:

Here I do not have padding mentioned for **salary** field, so what would be the value when marshalled to stream for `salary=8888`?
Will it be `008888` or `8888` (2 spaces followed by 8888)?

```
  <stream name="employeeFile">
    <record name="employee" class="example.Employee">
      <field name="firstName" length="10" />
      <field name="salary" length="6" justify="right" />
    </record> 
  </stream>
```

Comment: Have you tried marshalling that stream to see what it does? Have you read the documentation? Section 4.3.4 explain how padding works - http://beanio.org/2.1/docs/reference/index.html#FixedLengthFields

Comment: Yes, I went through the documentation on this link, but it's not clear what would be the padding for int field if not specified.

Answer (score 1):

Given your `mapping.xml` file, spaces will be used to pad the output when it is less than 6 digits long.

Using input of `firstname = "Learner"` and `salaray = 8888`, will produce the following output:

```
Learner     8888
```

There are 5 spaces in total between the end of the firstName (`Learner`) and the start of the salary's first digit (8). The first 3 spaces are the padding for the `firstName` field to make it of length 10. The next 2 spaces are the padding for the `salaray` field. The spaces appear in front of the `salaray` field because you specified that it should be right justified.

If you left it at the defaults, the `salary` field would be left justified, the default for all fields without specifying the `justify` attribute. Then the 2 spaces would be after the value of the `salary` field.

To see it better, let us change the `mapping.xml` file to use an asterisk (*) for padding the value of the `firstName` field and use a zero (0) for padding the `salary` field.

```
<stream name="employeeFile" format="fixedlength">
  <record name="employee" class="example.Employee">
    <field name="firstName" length="10" padding="*"/>
    <field name="salary" length="6" justify="right" padding="0"/>
  </record>
</stream>
```

This produces the following output:

```
Learner***008888
```

Answer (score 0):

It will actually be `8888__` (an underscore being a space character)

> By default, fixed length fields are left justified and padded with spaces [[1](http://beanio.org/2.1/docs/reference/index.html#FixedLengthFields)]